# Is correct use this count of IF?

Tags: php

I think my question is some stupid because the code work, I only want know if I can do it better hehe, I want get a text from a URL usin GET, but I want check if it is empty, check if the text have numbers, and if the text is not a option of two options required `condition_text_1` and `condition_text_2`, so I need do it with conditionals (IF), I will show my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['TEXT'])&&!empty($_GET['TEXT'])) {
  if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+$/", $_GET['TEXT'])) {
    $url = "DEFAULT_TEXT";
  }else{
    if ($_GET['TEXT'] !== 'condition_text_1' && $_GET['TEXT'] !== 'condition_text_2') {
      $url = "DEFAULT_TEXT";
    }else{
      $url = $_GET['TEXT'];
    }
  }
}else{
  $url = "DEFAULT_TEXT";
}
```

I dont know if its explained correct, but Im not talk english and Im new on php so it is a explosive post. Advanced thanks!!

Comment: You say this in your question *I only want know if I can do it better*. My question for you is, does it work as is, and if so, what do you want to accomplish by *better*? For example, what is your thought process on this failing in future unknown cases?

Comment: It can be simplified..

Comment: you could check PSR, PHP Standard Recommendation, like PSR-1 that explain Basic Coding Standard in PHP

Comment: @GetSet Hello!!, yes this code work perfectly, but it is the first gain I use if into others if and I only want now if the structure is correct, thanks for comment

Comment: @mik3fly-4steri5k thanks

Comment: Maybe `if(!empty($_GET['TEXT']) && in_array($_GET['TEXT'], array('condition_text_1', 'condition_text_2'))){ $url = $_GET['TEXT']; } else { $url = "DEFAULT_TEXT";}`

Comment: Agree with @user3783243, the `preg_match()` code is useless. Because it doesn't matter since you have definite sentinels you want to compare the "get" to, no need to "preg_match" it.

Comment: if you have many values to check with $_GET, you could write a function, 
function validate($var){ if (isset($var) && !empty($var)) { return true;} else { return false;} }

validate($_GET['TEXT']);

Comment: @user3783243 Thank, it work perfect are is more simplified

Comment: @GetSet Correct, I should have thought it, thanks

Comment: Am curious however why @ILOVEPHP this is the *only* part of your code you want simplified? Can you explain yourself?

Comment: @GetSet yes it is all, the problem was that he had never used if into others if, but now it is perfect!!

Comment: If you are curious about whether your code is good. you better to read php best practices guides or SOLID principles etc